# Postgresql Percentile

Tags: postgresql

So I need to find the 95th percentile of the age of arrestees in 2018 for a specific charge and  came up with this:

```
select
percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by age)
From arrests
Where chargegrpdesc like ‘Vehicle Theft’ and extract(year from adate) = ‘2018’;
```

The code runs, but I feel like it's too simple and I'm doing something wrong/not getting the correct result. I'm not exactly math-savvy and am new to sql so I just want to make sure I'm doing the right thing. Also, if there is any way I can clean up this query or make it more clear, please let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks OK to me!